# How to convert object array into Json array or Json string in ios swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an array which has set of objects `var quiz_anwers_list = [QuizQu]()` "QuizQu" is a Class which contains 2 variables

```
class QuizQu: Decodable {
    var ques_id: String?
    var their_answer: String?
}
```

Now am having,

```
for i in 0...self.quiz_anwers_list.count-1{

            print(self.quiz_anwers_list[i].ques_id ?? "no val in ques id of \(i)")
            print(self.quiz_anwers_list[i].their_answer ?? "no val in their_ans of \(i)")
        }
```

The output of those print is:

```
14
correct_answer
15
correct_answer2
16
correct_answer2
17
correct_answer
```

Now how can I convert this into JsonArray or JSON String? I am a new to iOS.

Comment: the print code is,
 `for i in 0...self.quiz_anwers_list.count-1{
            
            print(self.quiz_anwers_list[i].ques_id ?? "no val in ques id of \(i)")
            print(self.quiz_anwers_list[i].their_answer ?? "no val in their_ans of \(i)")
        }`

Comment: Please add information to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52497444/edit) it.

Comment: can u pls tell me the info. you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should probably be a struct and should conform to `Encodable`, not `Decodable`, if you plan to encode and decode you can use the `Codable` protocol which covers both cases.

Once you have done that, just use `JSONEncoder` to convert it to JSON data and then you can print it using `String(bytes: Sequence, encoding: String.Encoding)`

```
struct QuizQu: Codable {
    var ques_id: String?
    var their_answer: String?
}

let questions = [
    QuizQu(ques_id: "1", their_answer: "2"),
    QuizQu(ques_id: "2", their_answer: "2"),
    QuizQu(ques_id: "3", their_answer: "1"),
    QuizQu(ques_id: "4", their_answer: "4"),
    QuizQu(ques_id: "5", their_answer: "3")
]

do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(questions)
    print(String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Output:

> Optional("[{\"ques_id\":\"1\",\"their_answer\":\"2\"},{\"ques_id\":\"2\",\"their_answer\":\"2\"},{\"ques_id\":\"3\",\"their_answer\":\"1\"},{\"ques_id\":\"4\",\"their_answer\":\"4\"},{\"ques_id\":\"5\",\"their_answer\":\"3\"}]")

Note: the output String is escaped, hence the backslashes

Comment: `class QuizQu: Decodable, Encodable{}` i had just made my class like this. but am having this error "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"
`let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(quiz_anwers_list)` on this line

Comment: You can avoid the backslashes if you force unwrap the string. Creating UTF8 encoded JSON strings from `Data` cannot fail.

Comment: just now I had finished my code applying process. your code is perfect. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Great, Glad to help :)

Comment: am forced to unwrap the string but backslashes still existing. kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: this: `print(String(bytes: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)` does not show backslashes for me... `output: [{"ques_id":"1","their_answer":"2"},{"ques_id":"2","their_answer":"2"},{"ques_id":"3","their_answer":"1"},{"ques_id":"4","their_answer":"4"},{"ques_id":"5","their_answer":"3"}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
    extension Encodable {
      var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
      }
}

let struct = QuizQu(ques_id: 1, their_answer: abc)
let jsonObj = struct.dictionary
```

Comment: Why encode it with JSONEncoder and then decode it with JSONSerliazation to give a dictionary. The object is an array anyway so wouldn't work anyway, but encoding and straight away decoding just puts you back at the start. does something and undoes it.

Comment: Sorry, this code is not working in my case. it's coming as nil while try to extracting jsonObj.